# Read SerialPort in Maximum BaudRate in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I program an App in VB.Net and I want to read received data from a serial port in maximum baudrate. I used SerialPort component in my form and its properties are as follows:

> (BuadRate=115200 , DataBits=8 , Parity=None , StopBits=One)

When I use `connPort.ReadLine` in `DataReceived` event, data congestion caused in buffer and I can't read all received data in realtime, because event fires are slower than received data.

On the other side when I use `connPort.ReadExisting`, I can read all received data in realtime without data congestion in buffer, but the received data is look like this:

> First received: 
> -12917 
> -12958 
> -13004
>
> Second received: 
> -13055 
> -13118 
> -13181 
> -1324
>
> Third received: 
> 6 
> -13320 
> -13391 
> -13463

So I need to parser the received data line by line and on the other side I need to detect some received data errors look like:

> ... 
> -1324
>
> Third received: 
> 6 
> ...
>
> The correct data is: -13246

My code:

```
Private Sub connPort_DataReceived _
    (ByVal sender As System.Object, _
     ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) _
                                 Handles connPort.DataReceived
    Dim rcData as String
    rcData = connPort.ReadLine
    dt_Write(rcData)

    'rcData = connPort.ReadExisting
    'dt_Write(rcData)
End Sub

' Save received data in a created DataTable
Public dt As New DataTable
Private Sub dt_Write(ByVal rcData As String)
    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, rcData})
End Sub
```

I tried Timer component and `Tick` event With one millisecond Interval property (One millisecond is not real resolution) to receive data, but the fires are slower too and there are mentioned problems too.

I am looking for a right way and I'm trying to avoid redundant operations. Thank you

Comment: Can we see some code?  `ReadLine()` should work.  Did you set `connPort.Newline`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jim. I add my code in the question. When I use `connPort.ReadLine()`, I have some problems. At first I didn't define NewLine property but the rest I defined as `connPort.NewLine=Chr(13).ToString` in the Initialize, but it dosen't solve my problems and actually I could not find any difference.

Comment: What happens if you use `connPort.Read()` instead of `connPort.ReadLine()`?

Comment: @farzad89 Try `vbCr` for `Newline`.

Comment: If you do `connPort.Read()`, then you should be able to identify the `NewLine` character(s). Any reasonable person would have set it to either `Chr(13)` (vbCr) or `Chr(10)` (vbLf). Those are your two best bets.

Comment: If I use `connPort.Read()` method until NewLine character in the _DataReceived event, It work like `connPort.ReadLine` at every time the data is received. So data congestion caused in buffer and I can't read all received data in realtime.

Comment: Perhaps you should offload adding rows to your datatable to a background thread as that must be taking a lot of time for some reason if you can't `ReadLine` without the port buffer overflowing. If you were writing data to a textbox (properly since `DataReceived` event is not in the UI thread), it should fly by so fast you couldn't read it.

Comment: Maybe the line is too long and the buffer is overflowing. Use the comment on this question as a guide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021784/how-do-i-continuously-read-and-parse-high-speed-serialport-data?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for comments. As you see received data in every event fire is a string with 3 or 4 lines. Is it possible to limit this to receive one line in every fire ? or is it possible to use an another event with high speed fire ?

Comment: @topshot , Exactly, time is very important, and I tried to use high resolution timer to read data with a little fast, but until now I could not to get a result.

Comment: Depending on how long you need to capture, perhaps you should use a different collection that has better add performance than a datatable. I'm not sure which is the fastest but I'd have to think that pre-allocating an array of 100000 elements, for example, and then assigning each element would be quicker than adding 100000 rows to a datatable. You could move it to a datatable when you're done if needed. But you might also be better off rolling your own serial port class (see http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friends thanks for your comments. I had a problem with realtime data reading in using of SerialPort component  in Vb.Net and finally I found a Solution And I wanted to share with you.

As you know the `DataReceived` event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received and we have to use the `BytesToRead` property to determine how much data is left to be read in the buffer.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx

I tested a new way, the `While...End While` structure almost iterate one thousand times in 100 milliseconds. So it is fired very faster than any event so I have used this structure in the `DataReceived` event until the `BytesToRead` is greater than zero. With this strategy I was able to read the received data in realtime.

My code is:

```
Private Sub connPort_DataReceived _
(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
 ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) _
                             Handles connPort.DataReceived
    Dim rcData as String

    While connPort.BytesToRead > 0
        rcData = connPort.ReadLine
        dt_Write(rcData)
    End While

End Sub

' Save received data in a created DataTable
Public dt As New DataTable
Private Sub dt_Write(ByVal rcData As String)
    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, rcData})
End Sub
```

Comment: In addition, we can use `connPort.ReadTo(vbCrLf)` instead of `connPort.ReadLine`.